# IDLE 3.4.3 crashes when running module

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, crash, python-idle

I've recently started to use Python, and I don't know much about programming.

I've installed Python 3.4.3 in my Mac OS X Yosemite, and it worked fine for a few months, but now every time I want to run a module it stops responding.

so I use IDLE and when I open a new file to define a function I can write, then I click run and I save my file, and then when I click save IDLE doesn't restart as it use to and I can't write on it or do anything else. there is no crash report, no nothing, just all frozen. I close it and if then I re open and write on IDLE it works but as soon as I try to run a new file again it freezes.

How can I solve it?
to try stuff out i've been using repl.it online and it is useful for a learner like me but still I would like to be able to use IDLE on my mac.

THANK YOU FOR YOUR HELP!!!!

Comment: Are you trying to import something interactively (`>>> import os`) or run it from the command line (`$ python myscript.py`)? You need to be more specific, what command happens just before it freezes?

Comment: First of all, which module are you trying to run? Does this happen for all modules? Could you please show us the crash report, this could help. Please, edit your question with these details. There are [well known problems of using IDLE on a Mac OS X](https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/), mostly because of tkinter, since IDLE is written using tkinter (which is like a "translation" for  Python of the [Tk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tk_(software)) [GUI toolkit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widget_toolkit) for the [Tcl programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcl)).

Comment: Thank you!! I'll try to add the info but I'm kind of a newbie with programming so I'm not sure about stuff

Comment: Start Idle from the console with `python -m idlelib` and you may get an error report.  Otherwise, either repair or re-install Python, as it is pretty certain that either some file has been corrupted or some system setting has changed.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Anaconda](http://continuum.io/downloads), which is another Python distribution, but more science-oriented. It has all the commonly required modules already in it (plus other for scientific purposes), so that you don't have to install them as and when required. And when you install Anaconda, it automatically installs [Spyder](https://pythonhosted.org/spyder/#), which is a much better [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) than IDLE.

Comment: The issue of which installer to use is orthogonal to the issue of why Angie's installation quit working.

Comment: In my humble opinion, IDLE is better for folks just starting with Python.